# limit woocommerce product short description to max amount of characters

Tags: woocommerce

is there anyway to limit the characters/words that show in woocommerce product short product description that shows on shop/catalogue page? Sort of like an excerpt for a post.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strlen` to limit the characters in any string. I had implemented a similar logic in one of my custom plugins. I am sharing you the sample code and could be useful for you.

```
$thetitle = $post->post_excerpt; /* or you can use get_the_title() */
$getlength = strlen($thetitle);
$thelength = 50;
echo $thetitle = substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
if ($getlength > $thelength) {
   echo  $thetitle = $thetitle . '...';
}
```